# Call custom xquery function in eXist-db using url

Tags: xquery, exist-db

How to call a custom xquery function in exist-db using the REST API ?
Is it possible to have more than 1 function in the xquery file ?

```
declare function local:toto() as node() {
    return doc("/db/ProjetXML/alice.xml")/raweb/identification/projectName)
};

declare function local:pomme() as node() {
    return doc("/db/ProjetXML/carmen.xml")/raweb/identification/projectSize);
};
```

If I call it using :

```
http://localhost:8080/exist/rest/db/ProjetXML/orange.xqy?_query=local:toto()
```

I get the following error :

```
err:XPST0017 Call to undeclared function: local:toto [at line 1, column 1, source: local:toto()]
```

Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You have syntax errors in your XQuery:

1. You have two functions named `local:toto()`. Each function must have a distinct name.
2. There is no semicolon following the function definition, i.e. `}` should be `};`.
3. Also you should remove the `return` expression, as there is no preceding binding.

Another option would be to parameterize the input file, e.g.:

```
import module namespace request="http://exist-db.org/xquery/request";

declare function local:toto($name as xs:string) as node() {
  let $doc :=
      if($name eq "carmen")then
        doc("/db/ProjetXML/carmen.xml")
      else
        doc("/db/ProjetXML/alice.xml")
  return
    $doc/raweb/identification/projectName);
};

local:toto(request:get-parameter("name", "alice"))
```

You can then call this via the REST Server using a URL like:

```
  http://localhost:8080/exist/rest/db/ProjetXML/orange.xqy?name=carmen
```

Comment: Hello, I've fixed the syntax errors in the questions, but the real problem is calling a given xquery function using the url.

Comment: I just modified my answer to show how to call it via REST